# "Element is not clickable at point" because something is on top of it - How do I wait for it to be clickable?

Tags: ruby, ajax, watir-webdriver

Right now I'm just using dumb sleep statements, but there has GOT to be a better way to make things work than what I'm doing, right? I've tried `visible` and `until_present` but so far neither of them have the desired effect.

The element in particular is a table column header that, when clicked, will re-sort the table against it. When it is clicked, the table dims a little loading icon pops up, and the button is not clickable again until that icon is gone and the table re-brightens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post provided a solution: https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/element-is-not-clickable-due-to-another-element-that-would-receive-the-click/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find an element that is on top and wait until it won't be present like:

```
loading_element_on_top.wait_while_present
your_element.click
```

If you will provide more details (HTML of the page or even better the url, your code) I will give more detailed answer.